# python / django log in issue

Tags: python, django, postgresql, authentication

Currently, I have usertypes in this Python/Django project and I was able to log in as admin but I am not being able to log in as a student or staff I am using Postgres as data base can anyone please help me?

**models.py:**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type_data = ((1,"HOD"), (2,"Staff"), (3,"student"))
    user_type = models.CharField(default=1, choices=user_type_data, max_length=10)

class Admin(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()

class Staff(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()

class Students(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    profile_picture = models.FileField()
    address = models.TextField()
    course_id = models.ForeignKey(Courses, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    session_start_year = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    session_end_year = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()



@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.user_type==1:
            Admin.objects.create(admin=instance)
        if instance.user_type==2:
            Staff.objects.create(admin=instance)
        if instance.user_type==3:
            Students.objects.create(admin=instance, course_id = Courses.objects.get(id=1), session_start_year="2020-04-02", session_end_year="2022-01-01", profile_picture="", gender="")

@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.user_type==1:
        instance.admin.save()
    if instance.user_type==2:
        instance.staff.save()
    if instance.user_type==3:
        instance.students.save()
```

**here is my login view:**

```
def DoLogin(request):
    if request.method != "POST":
        return HttpResponse("<h2> Do log in first </h2>")
    
    else:
        user = EmailBackEnd.authenticate(request, username=request.POST.get("email"),password=request.POST.get("password"))
        if user != None:
            login(request, user)
            if user.user_type == "1":
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/admin_home")
            elif user.user_type == "2":
                return HttpResponse("Staff Login")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Student Login")
    
            
        else:
            messages.error(request,"Invalid Login Details")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/LoginPage")
```

**Emailbackend.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class EmailBackEnd(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password =None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        return None
```

**save student:**

```
def AddStudentSave(request):
    if request.method != "POST":
        return HttpResponse("Method Not Allowed")
    else:
        first_name = request.POST.get("first_name")
        last_name = request.POST.get("last_name")
        username = request.POST.get("username")
        address = request.POST.get("address")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        session_start_year = request.POST.get("session_start_year")
        session_end_year = request.POST.get("session_end_year")
        course_id = request.POST.get("course")
        gender = request.POST.get("gender")
        try:
            user = CustomUser.objects.create(username=username, password=password, email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, user_type=3)
            user.students.address=address
            course_obj = Courses.objects.get(id=course_id)
            user.students.course_id = course_obj
            user.students.session_start_year = session_start_year
            user.students.session_end_year = session_end_year
            user.students.gender = gender
            user.students.profile_picture = ""
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, "Student added successfully")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/AddStudent")
        except:
            messages.error(request, "Failed to add Student")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/AddStudent")
```

I am not sure what I got wrong in this code pls help me

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: when i lokk at the data base passwords of custom users are stored in an unencrypted format how can you resolve this???

Comment: Can you show how you saved the user? In the question, it's all about logging in

Comment: i added that code email backend.py and I have defined the usertypes in model itself

Comment: i saved the user types in models.py

Comment: how did you set the password

Comment: i was folowing a tutorial and i am not clear about the working can you explain it to me the set password

Comment: can you please tell me how to set the password in the current code

Comment: after creating the user, try to add: `user.set_password(password); user.save()`